# Duplicated text in Folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing, ticker

I've made a Folder in my application via [JWFolders](https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders). My problem is that I've set up some code to get some strings from parse.com and if there's no connection it diplays some text in a [CLTickerview](https://github.com/caydenliew/CLTickerView). However, if I open the folder a few times the text duplicates every time I open the folder. Here some Images:

After opening first time: [image]

After about 5 times: [image]

After 10 times: [image]

My code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"object1"
                             block:^(PFObject *textu, NSError *error) {
                                 if (!error) {
                                     // start the tickerview
                                    CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 35)];
                                    ticker.marqueeStr = [textu objectForKey:@"text"];
                                     ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];


                                     [self.view addSubview:ticker];

                                    // if there's connection

                                 } else {
                                     // Log details of our failure
                                     CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 35)];
                                     ticker.marqueeStr = @"Keine Internet Verbindung";
                                     ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];

                                     [self.view addSubview:ticker];

                                     //if there's no connection;

                                 }

                             }];
```

Is there a way to delete the stuff inside the tickerview, after the folder is closed or something like that?

Does have anyone suggestios or solutions for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each and every time you open the folder, you are creating separate instances of `CLTickerView *ticker` and adding to the view as subview using this line `[self.view addSubview:ticker];`. If you want to add that only once, you need to create the ticker in a place where you wont call the `alloc` method repeatedly.

Create in `viewDidLoad` or so,

```
CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 35)];
```

Then use it as,

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"object1"
                             block:^(PFObject *textu, NSError *error) {
                                 if (!error) {
                                     // start the tickerview

                                     ticker.marqueeStr = [textu objectForKey:@"text"];
                                     ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];
                                     [self.view addSubview:ticker];

                                    // if there's connection

                                 } else {
                                     // Log details of our failure
                                     ticker.marqueeStr = @"Keine Internet Verbindung";
                                     ticker.marqueeFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:26];

                                     [self.view addSubview:ticker];

                                     //if there's no connection;

                                 }

                             }];
```

Remember that whenever you call `CLTickerView *ticker = [[CLTickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 35)];`, it creates separate copies and you cant access the previous one, once the new one is created.

Whenever you want to remove it just use `[ticker removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: @NoahRaissi: Hey I made JWFolders. If you have any issues with it or if anything needs improvement, please post an issue on the repo and I'll be glad to help you out. :)

Comment: @sudorm-rf thank you a lot. I'm glad to hear from such an great developer like you. your open source project was very useful for me it's fantastic. I had some problems but solved them :D but one question I've got. How is it possible to give the backround items such a alpha decrease like apple do with their folders, that the view is focused on the folder that was clicked. Is it possible to do this. If yes...how? And do u have some more open source projects like this :D ?

Comment: @NoahRaissi: Ah, unfortunately there's no easy to go go about adding something like that. Since I'm taking a screen capture of the view before opening it up, any changes to the alpha of any of the views will not appear as changed until the folder closes. Of course there could be ways around this by simply splitting the actual view itself, but I could not generalize that into a library that would work for everyone, and as such I had to make compromises. And I do have a similar library for 3D swiping, but I had issues with it and never released it. :)

Comment: @sudorm-rf thanks at all for your great work and hilarious support for me :D see you soon